# RegEx for keeping lines ending with 1

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to delete lines that don't end with 1. For example

```
Cops1

Guns123

Jamesgunn10

Fire1
```

I would need a regex to keep only:

```
Cops1

Fire1
```

I have tried editing with this `^[^0-9]`, but I'm getting nowhere.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before `$` (anchor for the end of the line), match anything but 1 with `[^1]`:

```
^.*[^1]$\n?
```

Replace with the empty string.

https://regex101.com/r/yXWISP/1

If you don't want the possibility of an extra newline at the end, then alternate with `\n` at the beginning:

```
^.*[^1]$\n|\n^.*[^1]$
```

Comment: You sir are a legend it worked perfectly thank you so much. If its not to much trouble to ask, how could i edit this regex later on add on things for example, if i need to keep only lines ending in 9 or 12

Comment: If it's just one character, just replace the `1` with that character. For arbitrary lengths, negative lookahead for that substring for each repeated character, eg `^(?:(?!123$).)*$\n|\n^(?:(?!123$).)*$`

Comment: @Emma i clicked it, but i dont know if its closing this

Comment: @regexnoob75 Notepad++ uses a rich regex engine. You could try `^.*$(?<!1)\R*` instead.